# Classification of a linear transform in the form $A = B C B^{T}$

Tags: matrices

Is there some classification (a common name) for any given transform following the form $A = B C B^{T}$? (where A, B and C are three matrices, and $^T$ is the transpose operation) Is this a subset of linear transforms, right? Is there any more specific subset, with a name?

For instance, in the H.264/AVC video codec, one step is the Hadamard Transform, applied over a bunch of DC values of a DCT. Such transform is defined as: $T=H×D×H^T$. Another transform is the integer DCT, where the same formation exists, however the H matrix have other values.

I'm aiming with such question to identify properties of all those transformations following the same presented formation, once some classes of transforms, funcions, values or whatever commonly presents with a subset of properties.

Comment: this is generally used when $C$ is symmetric and $B$ is nonsingular. Other than that, I have no idea what you want.

Comment: For instance, in the H.264/AVC video codec, one step is the Hadamard Transform, applied over a bunch of DC values of a DCT. Such transform is defined as:

$T = H \times D \times H^{T}$

My question is about the existence of a classification (a common name) for all transforms following such formation.

Comment: in the real case, $A$ and $C$ are said to be *congruent*. We still require $B$ nonsingular. *Matrix Analysis* by Roger Horn and Charles Johnson. In expensive book, maybe you should buy it.

Comment: Not so simple to find such book here :( However I'll try to find it at the local library. I already tried some books, as _Matrix Computations_ by Gene H. Golub and Charles F. Van Loan. The problem is to find a common name for such operation. You gave me some classification to A, B and C, but none for the operation. The far I got was to linear transform. But it seems to me a plenty of other matrix operations are in the same set of "linear transforms".

Comment: mathematics typically emphasizes the equivalence relation rather than the mechanism that might be used to calculate different expressions for what is being regarded as the same thing; in the most general sense, this is a "change of basis." I do not have Golub and Van Loan, but if what you want is not in there then I suspect you have all you are going to get. Possibly engineers, computer science people, have a phrase for this.